# Entity Created OnModelCreating is not accessible in DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a many to many relationship mapping, and the mapping table has an additional field. I created the ApplicationDbContext as below:

```
        public virtual DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Region> Regions { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<CountryRegionMapping>()
                .HasKey(um => um.CountryRegionMappingId)
                .ToTable("CountryRegionMapping");

            modelBuilder.Entity<CountryRegionMapping>()
                .HasRequired(um => um.Region).WithMany(g => g.CountryMappings)
                .HasForeignKey(um => um.RegionId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<CountryRegionMapping>()
                .HasRequired(um => um.Country).WithMany(g => g.RegionMappings)
                .HasForeignKey(um => um.CountryId);

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
```

I was refering [this link](https://entityframework.net/knowledge-base/30899930/ef-code-first---many-to-many-relation-mapping-table-with-extra-columns) to create the Many-to-Many relationship having an extra field in the mapping table.

The entity classes are :

```
    public class Country
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string SystemOneName { get; set; }
        public string SystemTwoName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<CountryRegionMapping> RegionMappings { get; set; }
    }

    public class Region
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string SystemOneName { get; set; }
        public string SystemTwoName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<CountryRegionMapping> CountryMappings { get; set; }
    }

    public class CountryRegionMapping
    {
        public int CountryRegionMappingId { get; set; }
        public int CountryId { get; set; }
        public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
        public int RegionId { get; set; }
        public virtual Region Region { get; set; }
        public bool CheckField { get; set; }
    }
```

When I try to access the Country or Region tables I can simply access it through the code as below using dbcontext.Regions

```
ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
db.Regions.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Id == Id);
```

But when I try to access the "CountryRegionMapping" entity I cannot access through a code as db.CountryRegionMapping

Why is this not available in the Db Context. How can I access this entity in the middle of a Many-to-Many relationship.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the middle-mapping entities directly, add those as a `DbSet` on your context, along with the other ones:

```cs
public virtual DbSet<CountryRegionMapping> CountryRegionMappings { get; set; }

public virtual DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Region> Regions { get; set; }
```

Then you can access them same as you access `Countries`, or `Regions`:

```cs
ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
db.CountryRegionMappings//.SingleOrDefault, etc.
```

Comment: Tried that but not getting any results from the bridge table. Im getting nothing. The count is 0. Im using Entity Framework 6.2.0 by the way not core

Comment: Do you have any data there in the database?